# Compiling examples from GLFW?

Tags: opengl, glfw

I am trying to compile the file **simple.c** in **glfw-3.2.1/examples** on Ubuntu 18.04. I am using the following compilation command:

```
gcc -o simple simple.c glad.c -lglfw3 -lGL -lm -lXrandr -lXi -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lpthread -ldl -lXinerama -lXcursor
```

I have copied and pasted glad.c and glad.h into this examples folder, as well as the include folder that came with glad.zip

However, I when I try to compile the code I get the following:

```
glad.c:25:10: fatal error: glad/glad.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glad/glad.h>
```

I don't understand why this is, since I am including glad.c in the compilation command.

I am following this tutorial to set up glad https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Creating-a-window. Unfortunaly, this opengl tutorial is geared towards MS Windows. Is there an easier way to set up glad on Ubuntu (sudo apt install ...)?

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including `glad.c` in the compilation command will not bring the header in, it will compile `glad.c` and bring in the object from the generated file in (so it would be somewhat close to `-lglad` if you had installed some glad library)

Unfortunately there does not seem to be any ubuntu package for glad, the next simplest thing would be to simply compile the examples along with glfw (just run cmake and make in the glfw folder), but we can fix that anyway.

### Understanding the error

`glad.c:25:10: fatal error: glad/glad.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glad/glad.h>`

says "the file glad.c wants a header located in glad/glad.h, but I cannot find it"

This can either be a problem with include paths (gcc is not looking in the directories you intended it to look at), or the file really is not here.

Looking at `glad.c` and `simple.c`, they use this syntax:

`#include <glad/glad.c`

Includes can be of two kinds, either through double-quotes in which case they are called "local includes" and gcc will look for the headers in the current directory, or with angle brackets and they are usually "system includes"; you need to tell gcc where to look for them with the `-I` option

### Fixing it

There are multiple ways to fix that.

- We can use a command line/environment the c files expect.

First, respect the zip hierarchy, the post you linked to says there should be two include directories, so you need to put the headers where they were in the zip file (glad.h in the glad directory) ;

then tell gcc to look for include files in the current directory with `-I.` (. is the current directory)

The command line will then look like something like `gcc -o simple simple.c glad.c -I. -lglfw3 -l...`

or

- change simple.c and glad.c to include `"glad.h"` instead of `<glad/glad.h>` ; the files will then look for the file where you had it automatically.

Having tried to compile `simple.c` the same way you did now, you will also need a `linmath.h` header; I am not sure if it comes with glad but glad and `linmath.h` are in the `deps` directory of glfw in the git tree, I would assume they also are in the tar.

Comment: Do you mean to copy/paste the **glad** folder and respective contents in the *glfw-3.2.1/examples* folder? that brings the same error

Comment: No, you need to have a glad.h in a glad folder in the directory where you try to compile (or in any system include directory, or directory you add with `-I <dir>` -- I'm pretty sure it looks in the current directory by default)

Comment: I have put a (**glad** folder containing a **glad.h** file) and a (**KHR** folder containing a **khrplatform.h**) inside the **glfw-3.2.1/examples** folder, but it still won't find <glad/glad.h>

Comment: Yeah, sorry - headers included with `<>` are not looked at in the current directory, you need to explicitly add it with `-I.` - I'll amend the answer

Comment: What would my compilation command look like? I am trying "gcc -o simple simple.c -I glad/ -lglfw3 -lGL -lm -lXrandr -lXi -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lpthread -ldl -lXinerama -lXcursor'' but I am getting the same error of not finding glad :(

Comment: No, it's still looking for glad/glad.h -- so `gcc -o simple simple.c glad.c -I. -lglfw3 ...`

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have helped! Now I am getting fatal error: linmath.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Yeah, I was re-editing the answer and posted about linmath.h as well. It's another requirement for simple, you should be able to find it in the glfw's deps directory in the sources (or maybe the tutorial talks about it, I didn't read it carefully)

Comment: Thanks! You helped a lot!